# list index out of range in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe

```
          0            1
0  12:45:12   This is a tweet
1  12:47:12   tweet number 2
2  12:48:12   tweet 3
```

I wanted to name the heads I used the code below

```
list_of_dicts = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    temp_dict = {}
    temp_lst = df.iloc[i,0].split("|")

    temp_dict['time'] = temp_lst[0]
    temp_dict['tweet'] = temp_lst[1]

    list_of_dicts.append(temp_dict)
```

but its giving me the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-4a91a680754d> in <module>()
      5 
      6     temp_dict['time'] = temp_lst[0]
----> 7     temp_dict['tweet'] = temp_lst[1]
      8 
      9     list_of_dicts.append(temp_dict)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change to split(":")

in your code you use temp_lst = df.iloc[i,0].**split("|")**

UPDATE:

Oh I see you want to get columns.Ignore the above answer.Don't need split. Just use

`df.iloc[i].tolist()`

Comment: @kavya sharma, You can change the column index of dataframe directly, and use it to index you data.What you did is to create a list of dict